# mysql return a record which is not the same as last record

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

Here is my query

```
SELECT `orders_status_id` FROM orders_status_history 
WHERE `orders_id`='15' ORDER BY `date_added` DESC LIMIT 1, 1
```

What I need was to get the second last record from a bunch of records.The above query is working at this point but now I want to place filter that if the second last record is empty or same as last then move one record previous.

[image]

As you can see second last record for `orders_status_id` is 17 (same as the last record) so it should return me "8"(move one step up). Same case applied when the second last record is empty then move one step up. In this example if instead of "8" it was "17" or empty then it should move one more step up until it is not same as last or empty.

thanks

EDITED:
this is the error I am getting
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method may be to use variables:

```
SELECT osh.*
FROM (SELECT osh.orders_status_id,
             (@rn := if(@osi = osh.orders_status_id, @rn,
                        if(@osi := osh.orders_status_id, @rn + 1, @rn + 1)
                       )
             ) rn
      FROM orders_status_history osh CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0, @osi := -1) params
      WHERE orders_id = 15
      ORDER BY date_added DESC
     ) osh
WHERE rn = 2
LIMIT 1;
```

This enumerates the different values of `order_status_id`, choosing the second value that appears.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..

Please review my question again have attached the error message I am getting after applying your query.